# HTML5 form validation not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having the below form in bootstrap modal but the HTML5 validation is not working in it and throwing error in console that 'An invalid form control with name='mobile' is not focusable.'

```
<div id="registermodal1" class="modal register-modal" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
 <form role="form" class="reg_form">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header vostro-modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 titleSideBar">
        <h5 style="color: #fff;">Create Cavein</h5>
<h5 style="color: #fff;">Account</h5>
<br><br><br><br>
<h5 style="color: #fff;">100% Genuine Owners, 0% Brokerage.</h5><br><br>
<img src="<?php  echo base_url('assets/images/house.png'); ?>">

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 mainContainer form">

          <div class="control-group">
                    <h6 style="font-size: 16px;color: #fff;padding-bottom: 5px;">Your contact number is necessary for us to verify your identity</h6>
```

Enter your mobile nomber.
                        
    +91

```
          </div>
          <br>


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

    <button class="lof"><div class="loader"></div></button>
    <button type="submit" id="next_1" class="btn btn-next my-btn">Next</button>
  </div>

</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I don't see a form element named mobile

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `novalidate` attribute to the form will help:

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, You might have hidden input having required attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" required />
```

Hence form can't focus on that element, you have to remove required from all hidden inputs.